# Need fixes for a few errors-Python

Tags: python

Okay so I almost have this problem figured out but still need some help. I just need the program to display an error message when the speed is less than 0 after braking, then reset it to 0. Thanks for any help

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

############# year_model################
    def setYear_model(self, year_model):
        self.__year_model = year_model

    def getYear_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

############# Make################
    def setMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def getMake(self):
        return self.make

############# speed################
    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        if speed < 0:
            print("Speed cannot be negative")
        else:
            self.__speed = speed

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def accelerate(self, speed):
        self.__speed += 5
        return self.__speed

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5
        return self.__speed

############# str ############
    def __str__(self):
        return "Make : " + self.__make + ", Model Year :" + \
        self.__year_model + ", speed = " + str(self.__speed)
```

Here is the code that is suppose to run this definition:

```
import CarDefinition

def main():
    # Create an instance of Car
    my_car = CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")
    print(my_car)
    print("my_car after instantiating:\n", my_car)

    my_car.setSpeed(2)
    print("my_car after my_car.setSpeed(2):\n", my_car)
    # Accelerate 5 times
    print ("car is accelerating: ")
    for i in range(5):
        my_car.accelerate()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print()
    # Brake 7 times
    print ("car is braking: ")
    for i in range(7):
        my_car.brake()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print("my_car values at program end:\n", my_car)


main()
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have some underscores being used inconsistently

Comment: Allan, it's not a good idea to change the topic of your question "in mid-stream". Two people spent time to look through and analyze your code and, essentially, point out "typo" errors. If you change your question to wanting an error message, those Answers aren't going to make any sense (to say nothing of the fact that this question is going to be closed). You should start a *new* question for a new topic/requirement.

Comment: My question got "put on hold" for being too broad so I thought I should change it.

Comment: I got a notification saying my question had been "put on hold" for being too broad, so I thought it was best to change the question. Also, it won't let me ask another question as this one was asked yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__` method and in some other places you refer to `self.__speed`. However, in your `accelerate` and `brake` methods you refer to `self.speed`, which is not the same thing. Make all the references the same and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: i just tried that and it didn't work unfortunately. It still displays 2 for everything.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rory's answer, in your main code you never actually call the `accelerate` and `brake` methods. You always need to use the calling parentheses `()` to invoke a function or method, rather than just refer to it.

However if you do that you will encounter another problem, which is that those methods have been defined to accept a parameter, `speed`, which you would need to pass. But in fact those methods don't use those parameters, so you should remove them from the definitions. So:

```
def accelerate(self):
    self.__speed += 5
    return self.speed

def brake(self):
    self.__speed -= 5
    return self.speed

...

for i in range(5):
    my_car.accelerate()

...

for i in range(5):
    my_car.brake()
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and now it says that there is an error on "line 21, in main my_car.brake() TypeErrorL brake() missing 1 required positional argument: 'speed'

Comment: Then you didn't do what I suggested, because I said to take out that argument.

Comment: Okay I got it to work, but I also need it to display an error message when the speed is less than 0 after braking, then reset it to 0. Thank you for any help.